# Facebook Closed Group Members for App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/members) it is stated that one can list members of group and permissions required for this action are

> Any valid access token if the group's privacy setting is either OPEN or CLOSED.

Any valid access token implies that I could use **App token**. But using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%7Bgroup-id%7D%2Fmembers&version=v2.5) and App Token, when the group is Closed, data returned is empty. This works only when the group is Public. If I try to use User Access Token, everything is fine.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The docs are just wrong. You can not use an app token if the group is closed.

Comment: Thanks @WizKid. After registering bug at facebook and they confirmed, now I know it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, it is a bug and facebook has [confirmed it](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/722589454539074/). Waiting for fix or at least documentation change.

Comment: Is it possible now any way to access closed group member details?